# Why does Googling your Stack Exchange username show your questions and answers on non-SE websites in various languages?

Tags: support

I Google myself, and I would like to know why most of the 3120 search results for my username are rehashed questions and answers from Stack Exchange. What's the incentive for these website makers? Are there just a lot of knock off botsites that rehash everything Stack Exchange to steal clicks?

- http://ambracode.com/index/show/1627899
- http://linux2biz.net/164910/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-hash-function-sha1
- http://www.28im.com/python/a3850161.html
- http://physics.troplet.com/question/is-thermal-and-electrical-conductivity-correlated-for-all-phases-of-matter-201058.html

Biology fashion photo? What what?
 - http://biology.fashionphoto.win/users/8570/mattkaeo